# Cube.js React Hook React.useCallback has a missing dependency: 'pivotConfig'. +

Tags: javascript, node.js, reactjs, npm, cube.js

I've been trying to create a simple dashboard with Cube.js using windows 10 and Mysql version 8.

I originally tried a Js backend, fought with the install for a few days, then tried a docker install but quit after a few hours of error messages, and now am back to the node.js backend. My guess is Cube.js isn't updated or maintained anymore.

Using

> npx cubejs-cli create ihatecubejs -d whyamIstilltrying

I get:

> ```
> npm WARN ERESOLVE overriding peer dependency
> npm WARN While resolving: dashboard-app@0.1.0
> npm WARN Found: react@17.0.2
> npm WARN node_modules/react
> npm WARN   peer react@"*" from @testing-library/react@11.2.7
> npm WARN   node_modules/@testing-library/react
> npm WARN     @testing-library/react@"^11.2.7" from the root project
> npm WARN   6 more (react-dom, react-scripts, the root project, ...)
> npm WARN
> npm WARN Could not resolve dependency:
> npm WARN peer react@"17.0.2" from react-dom@17.0.2
> npm WARN node_modules/react-dom
> npm WARN   peer react-dom@"*" from @testing-library/react@11.2.7
> npm WARN   node_modules/@testing-library/react
> npm WARN   3 more (the root project, @ant-design/compatible, antd)
> npm WARN ERESOLVE overriding peer dependency
> npm WARN While resolving: dashboard-app@0.1.0
> npm WARN Found: react@17.0.2
> npm WARN node_modules/react
> npm WARN   peer react@"*" from @testing-library/react@11.2.7
> npm WARN   node_modules/@testing-library/react
> npm WARN     @testing-library/react@"^11.2.7" from the root project
> npm WARN   6 more (react-dom, react-scripts, the root project, ...)
> npm WARN
> npm WARN Could not resolve dependency:
> npm WARN peer react@"17.0.2" from react-dom@17.0.2
> npm WARN node_modules/react-dom
> npm WARN   peer react-dom@"*" from @testing-library/react@11.2.7
> npm WARN   node_modules/@testing-library/react
> npm WARN   3 more (the root project, @ant-design/compatible, antd)
> npm WARN ERESOLVE overriding peer dependency
> npm WARN While resolving: dashboard-app@0.1.0
> npm WARN Found: react@17.0.2
> npm WARN node_modules/react
> npm WARN   peer react@"*" from @testing-library/react@11.2.7
> npm WARN   node_modules/@testing-library/react
> npm WARN     @testing-library/react@"^11.2.7" from the root project
> npm WARN   6 more (react-dom, react-scripts, the root project, ...)
> npm WARN
> npm WARN Could not resolve dependency:
> npm WARN peer react@"17.0.2" from react-dom@17.0.2
> npm WARN node_modules/react-dom
> npm WARN   peer react-dom@"*" from @testing-library/react@11.2.7
> npm WARN   node_modules/@testing-library/react
> npm WARN   3 more (the root project, @ant-design/compatible, antd)
> npm WARN deprecated core-js@1.2.7: core-js@<3.3 is no longer maintained and not
> ```

Then:

```
Compile Failed-
./src/components/Header.js
Attempted import error: 'withRouter' is not exported from 'react-router'.
```

is fixed with:

`npm install react-router@5`

`npm install react-router-dom@5`

Then a ton of warning messages (one being deprecated UUID (version 3.4)- it's not installed though) that are ignored.

running npm start dev in the project directory opens the dev panel and running 'generate scheme' creates a scheme for each of my 2 connected databases in the
"cube.js_test\ihatecubejs\schema" folder but none of the variables in the database are carried over.

I manually enter a handful of variables in the schema and get a chart to show in the development panel. A chart is generated, incorrectly, and I specify that I want time to be ordered- which throws an error but works on refresh. Whatever.

Now to create a dashboard app with the one chart:

Error: " "category" is not a registered scale." or

[image: Loading wheel does burnout]

The console says:

> Compiled with warnings.
>
> src\components\ChartRenderer.js   Line 78:5:  React Hook
> React.useCallback has a missing dependency: 'pivotConfig'. Either
> include it or remove the dependency array  react-hooks/exhaustive-deps

But pivotConfig seems to be defined in the DashboardPage.js in the /src folder.

I can't figure it out and I'm gonna barf if I spend any more time on this. Any help is much appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

As for dashboards, they seem to be fixed, I've tried today. And as for the Cube, they still maintain it:
https://github.com/cube-js/cube.js

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).